# ar_pose_marker from ar_pose packge not published

Tags: ros, ar-pose, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run the ar_pose package and read the ar_pose_marker_ data. I did the following

I have the following two packages :
1- ar_pose
2- uvc_camera

I run the following two launch files:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_marker"  args="0 1 1 -1.57 3.14 -1.57 world ar_marker 10" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="marker_to_cam" args="0 0 0.5 0 0 0 ar_marker camera 10" />
<node ns="camera" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" name="image_proc"/>
<node name="ar_pose" pkg="ar_pose" type="ar_single" respawn="false" output="screen">
   <param name="marker_pattern" type="string" value="data/4x4/4x4_1.patt"/>
   <param name="marker_width" type="double" value="152.4"/>
   <param name="marker_center_x" type="double" value="0.0"/>
   <param name="marker_center_y" type="double" value="0.0"/>
   <param name="threshold" type="int" value="100"/>
   <param name="use_history" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <param name="reverse_transform" type="bool" value="true"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

Then I run the camera launch file

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="uvc_camera" type="uvc_camera_node" name="uvc_camera" output="screen" ns="/camera">

    <param name="width" type="int" value="320" />
    <param name="height" type="int" value="240" />
    <param name="fps" type="int" value="30" />
    <param name="frame" type="string" value="camera" />
   <param name="auto_focus" type="bool" value="False" />
   <param name="focus_absolute" type="int" value="0" />
   <!-- other supported params: auto_exposure, exposure_absolute, brightness, power_line_frequency -->

   <param name="device" type="string" value="/dev/video0" />
   <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="file://$(find uvc_camera)/example.yaml" />
 </node>
</launch>
```

Then I run RVIZ  and I put the fixed frames world.
I could not find the ar_pose_marker_  at all ?? is there a plug-in for it since it is type of ARMARKER msgs
Also, I cant see anything on top of the images as provided in the package description
In addition, I tried to subscribe for the ar_pose_marker but there is no data as if the node ar_pose_single is not publishing it

How can I fix this and get the ar_pose_marker_ data ???

I attached Image for the rqt_graph and the output from Rviz for tf, camera , and the command line that shows that there are no output for the ar_pose_marker topic

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

EDIT:

The launch file has been edited to add the marker in the ground to be as ( 0, 0, 0) position or we can say that is is equal to the world frame and we remove the transformation between the camera and the marker because we actually need to obtain the position of the camera.. therefore the launch file will become as the following:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_marker"  args="0  0 0 0 0 0 world ar_marker 10" />
<node ns="camera" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" name="image_proc"/>
<node name="ar_pose" pkg="ar_pose" type="ar_single" respawn="false" output="screen">
   <param name="marker_pattern" type="string" value="data/4x4/4x4_1.patt"/>
   <param name="marker_width" type="double" value="152.4"/>
   <param name="marker_center_x" type="double" value="0.0"/>
   <param name="marker_center_y" type="double" value="0.0"/>
   <param name="threshold" type="int" value="100"/>
   <param name="use_history" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <param name="reverse_transform" type="bool" value="true"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243184/ar_pose_marker-from-ar_pose-packge-not-published/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if all that you want is to know the pose of the marker (or of the camera, according to your setup), you can obtain that from their tf frames.
the markers are drawn based on that information.

if you definitely need the visual markers, what is the output from a `rostopic info ar_pose_marker` ?

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2016-09-18**:
@Procópio There is no output from the ar_pose_marker. I actually Edited the question because I need to obtain the position of the camera. but I still don not know which topic will give me the position of the camera or I should only read the tf of the camera? how it will be generated in this pkg?

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2016-09-18**:
@Procópio Whan I do that, I dont receive anything from the ar_pose_marker topic also, the output in rviz is only the camera view. nothing like in the package description

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-09-19**:
how your tf tree looks like? do you get any feedback on the detection of the marker?